# Load content from one div into another div on click

Tags: jquery

I want to load the contents of various `<li>` into a single `<div>` when each `<li>` is clicked. Each time a new `<li>` is clicked, it should then unload the current contents and load its contents into the `<div>`.

```
<div id="main-content">Text that will be replaced</div>

<li class="title">1 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<li class="title">2 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<li class="title">3 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<li class="title">4 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
```

How can I make this work with jQuery? Seems like it shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm a bit of a jQuery neophyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right.  This is easy in `jQuery`.

1. learn about **selectors**(class and id) .
2. event handlers(`click`) and event handler attachments[(`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).
3. DOM Maniplation([`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/))

---

```
$('.title').on('click', function () {
    $('#main-content').text($(this).text());
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GgaAL/)

**Update:** from your comments

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="main-content">Text that will be replaced</div>
<li class="title">1 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<li class="title">2 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<li class="title">3 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<li class="title">4 - This will replace "main-content" text when clicked</li>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.title').on('click', function () {
    $('#main-content').text($(this).text());
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this as a separate file.  My concern is that you're not properly importing the `jQuery`.

Comment: I tried this (and the other examples given), and for some reason it won't work for me. I'm working from Wordpress. Copied the code into my miscellaneous .js file that is properly enqueued (as is jQuery), and I'm getting nothing.

Comment: I also tried using it straight in the Wordpress template file (both as is and by changing "$" to "jQuery"), and still got nothing.

Comment: @user2439212 what you're trying is achieved on JSFiddle right.  where are you adding the html?

Comment: Yes, that's why I can't understand why this won't work. Everything is in its proper place. The javascript is in the .js file, jQuery is loaded, and the html is in the body. As I said, I've tried it several ways and nothing happens at any point.

Comment: @user2439212 Check my updated answer.  Try adding this as a separate file and check what mistake you made.

Comment: Like a super dumbass, I had mispelled "document" and didn't notice.

Comment: @user2439212 usually happens ;) this is where `console (develper tools)` helps you.

Comment: Very true. Been staring at this project so long today that it didn't even cross my mind to check...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as below.

```
$('.title').on('click',function(){

    $('#main-content').html($(this).html());

});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/62mFx/1/)

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan okay i did deleted them now okay.?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.title').click(function(){
    $('div#main-content').text(this.text());
})
```

or use 'html' method instead of 'text' if you want to move also html content